# Scrapy - Get data in Form

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm absolutely new to scraping. I've wrote a script to scrape prices from [eoasia](http://eoasia.com), so far I can get this data with no problems:

```
{'location': [u'Khmer Ceramics Clay Workshop'], 'price': [u'$15']}
```

I'm trying to scrape the details from the booking form in [this](http://www.eoasia.com/en/cambodia/siem-reap/activities/7-khmer-ceramics-clay-workshop-around-siem-reap) page. Kindly click the 'Book Now' button. (I'd post an image but I can't yet)

Now, how would I go about having scrapy populate the fields (Date, Adults, Time) in the form?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booking of your example url happens through next url (don't forget https and utf8 parameter)

https://www.eoasia.com/en/cambodia/siem-reap/activities/7-khmer-ceramics-clay-workshop-around-siem-reap/bookings/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93

Now you need to add parameters with your values

```
booking[start_date]
booking[start_time]
booking[adults]
booking[children]
```

Example of finished booking url:

https://www.eoasia.com/en/cambodia/siem-reap/activities/7-khmer-ceramics-clay-workshop-around-siem-reap/bookings/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&booking[start_date]=29+Mar+2015&booking[start_time]=21%3A02&booking[adults]=2&booking[children]=3

You can visit last url and scrape the data you need

Comment: Thanks! I will try this for the other sites I have to scrape. I ended up scraping data from parsing the json endpoint I found in https://www.eoasia.com/en/cambodia/siem-reap/activities/7/price_check?start_date=29+Mar+2015&adults=3&children=3&currency=USD

Comment: You should also look into selenium. Selenium can imitate a browser to process javascript forms and pagination. Selenium with python: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/